# not able to get property using context:property-placeholder (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to read properties from "file" but not able to achive same.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jodo.image.*"></context:component-scan>

<context:property-placeholder location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/db.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties"/>

<util:properties id="systemPropertiesHolder" location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties">
</util:properties>
```

### 1st try

Class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread {
    private String rawImagePath;

    @Value("#{systemPropertiesHolder.rawImagePath}")
    public void setRawImagePath(String property){
        rawImagePath = property;
    }...
```

Result : rawImagePath is null

### 2nd try

Class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:properties-config.xml")
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread {
    private @Value("${rawImagePath}") String rawImagePath;
```

properties-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
  <context:property-placeholder location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Result : rawImagePath is null

### 3rd try

Class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties")
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread {
    @Autowired 
    Environment environment;
    private String rawImagePath;
    public void run() {
        if(environment == null){
                logger.info("environment is NULL");
            }
            rawImagePath = this.environment.getProperty("rawImagePath");
        ...
```

Give java.lang.NullPointerException (environment itself is null)

### 4th try

Class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread { 
    @Value("${rawImagePath}")
    private String rawImagePath;
```

Result : rawImagePath is null

### 5th try

ApplicationContext.xml (now placed all file in one property-placeholder)

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/db.properties, file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties"/>
```

Class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread { 
    @Value("${rawImagePath}")
    private String rawImagePath;
```

Result : rawImagePath is null

### 6th try

class ThreadFileImageUpload

```
package com.jodo.image.util;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread { 
    @Value("#{systemPropertiesHolder.rawImagePath}")
    private String rawImagePath;
```

AppliactionContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jodo.image.*"></context:component-scan>
<util:properties id="systemPropertiesHolder" location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties">
</util:properties>
```

Still getting it null

I am sure that property file has required field

```
[root@localhost /]# cat /usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties 
rawImagePath=/var/jodo-images/raw/
```

I am still stuck in same place.

Comment: In your 5th try, is `ThreadFileImageUpload` a Spring Bean?

Comment: What is the package name of the ThreadFileImageUpload class?

Comment: @Shinichi package com.jodo.image.util;

Comment: @geoand no, it is not spring bean

Comment: Is ThreadFileImageUpload annotated at the class level with the  `@Component` or other stereotype annotations in your 1st try? To make `@Value` work, ThreadFileImageUpload instance must be a Spring managed component.

Comment: @Shinichi, no, it is not annotated with any spring annotation in 1st, 4th and 5th try. Should i try "@Component" ??
It is thread and may have instance in hundred at one time.

Comment: i tried ""@Component
public class ThreadFileImageUpload extends Thread { 
 @Value("#{systemPropertiesHolder.rawImagePath}")
 private String rawImagePath;
with ApplicationContext.xml having "<util:properties id="service" location="file:/usr/local/jodo/opt/cms-image/service.properties">"

Still null

Comment: How do you get the ThreadFileImageUpload instance?

Comment: @ShinichiKai
ThreadFileImageUpload thread = new ThreadFileImageUpload(productId, imgFile, batchId, count);
thread.start();

Comment: Instances created using "new" are not managed by Spring. I would suggest reading the reference manual [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) to understand Spring bean.

Comment: @ShinichiKai, :O. u r right. I am able to print it in service class which is creating thread. Thx all of you for putting afford on this question (which i feel is now not a worth one).

Comment: @ShinichiKai, can u please add this as solution, so that i can mark it as answer. This will help newcomer like me for future

Comment: I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make @Value work, ThreadFileImageUpload instance must be a Spring managed component. Please note that instances created using "new" are *not* managed by Spring. The reference manual [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) may help you to understand Spring beans and component scanning.

Comment: moving "@Value" annotated attribute to service class(as it is not created through "new" and annotated "@Service") solved the issue. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Whevever you inject properties using @Value, the class your are injecting into needs to be a Spring bean. To make that happen you need to either annotate ThreadFileImageUpload with @Component and make sure that the class in a package that is within the component scan, or you need to add that bean manually (in this case into ApplicationContext.xml)

Comment: moving "@Value" annoted attribute to service class(as it is not created through "new" and annotated "@Service") solved the issue. thx geoand for annotation suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the name(root) of the properties. 
See this http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/61645-value-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer

If the file is `service.properties` and you have

```
`<util:properties id="service" location="classpath:com/acme/app/service.properties"/>`
```

then try `@Value("#{service.rawImagePath}")`

Comment: Hi Evgeni, i am still getting it null after changing to  @Value("${service.rawImagePath}"). plus issue is sth else as if this is the case, then try 1st will be successful. (In 1st try, i am setting it from bean "systemPropertiesHolder")

Comment: did you tried using id in the <util:properties element. See edit.

Comment: not solved Evgeni. Even in link pasted, property file is "myprops.properties" and id is "myProps". Filename and bean id is not linked